# DEVIO-I ESP32 struck in loop and reboot again and again while communicating with MQTT Broker

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp32, hivemq

I am using a [DEVIO NB-DEVKIT I](https://store.ais.co.th/th/devio-nb-devkit-i.html) (support NB-IOT) to connect to the public broker of [HiveMQ](http://www.mqtt-dashboard.com/).

I am using the [code](https://github.com/AIS-DeviceInnovation/Magellan_SIM7020E/blob/master/examples/MQTT/SimplePUBSUB/SimplePUBSUB.ino) provided by AIS(Telecom service in Thailand) Team.

I set the following settings in the Code:

```
String address    = "broker.hivemq.com";          //Your IPaddress or mqtt server url
String serverPort = "1883";               //Your server port
String clientID   = "mclient1";               //Your client id < 120 characters
String topic      = "my/test/topic";               //Your topic     < 128 characters
String payload    = "HelloWorld!";    //Your payload   < 500 characters
String username   = "";               //username for mqtt server, username <= 100 characters
String password   = "";               //password for mqtt server, password <= 100 characters
```

The ESP32 controller after establishing the connection restarts again and again and is struck in this loop.

The error message is shown below.

```
13:37:31.622 -> >>Signal : -63 dBm
13:37:31.807 -> >>Connecting ..............OK
13:37:41.735 -> >>APN   : DEVKIT.NB
13:37:41.735 -> ---------- Connected ----------
13:37:47.263 -> # ServerIP : broker.hivemq.com
13:37:47.263 -> # Port : 1883
13:37:47.263 -> # ClientID : mclient1
13:37:47.297 -> -------------------------------
13:37:47.297 -> # Subscribe 
13:37:47.297 -> # Topic : my/test/topic
13:37:47.297 -> Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
13:37:47.297 -> 
13:37:47.297 -> Core  1 register dump:
13:37:47.297 -> PC      : 0x400d43bc  PS      : 0x00060e30  A0      : 0x800d43b4  A1      : 0x3ffb2680  
13:37:47.297 -> A2      : 0x00000003  A3      : 0x3ffc27f0  A4      : 0x00000003  A5      : 0x00000001  
13:37:47.297 -> A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0x3f4006fd  A8      : 0x800d5056  A9      : 0x3ffb26a0  
13:37:47.330 -> A10     : 0x00000002  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x0000000a  A13     : 0x0000ff00  
13:37:47.330 -> A14     : 0x00ff0000  A15     : 0xff000000  SAR     : 0x00000015  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c  
13:37:47.330 -> EXCVADDR: 0x00000087  LBEG    : 0x400862e1  LEND    : 0x400862f1  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff  
13:37:47.330 -> 
13:37:47.330 -> 
13:37:47.330 -> Backtrace: 0x400d43b9:0x3ffb2680 0x400d43b1:0x3ffb26e0 0x400d2293:0x3ffb2700 0x400d1741:0x3ffb2740 0x400d181b:0x3ffb27c0 0x400d63d6:0x3ffb2820
13:37:47.370 -> 
13:37:47.370 -> 
13:37:47.370 -> 
13:37:47.370 -> 
13:37:47.370 -> ELF file SHA256: 632709499e5776f5
13:37:47.370 -> 
13:37:47.449 -> Rebooting...
13:37:47.449 -> ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
13:37:47.449 -> 
13:37:47.449 -> rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
13:37:47.449 -> configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
13:37:47.449 -> clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
13:37:47.449 -> mode:DIO, clock div:1
13:37:47.449 -> load:0x3fff0030,len:1344
13:37:47.449 -> load:0x40078000,len:13836
13:37:47.495 -> load:0x40080400,len:3608
13:37:47.495 -> entry 0x400805f0
13:37:47.573 -> >>Rebooting ...OK
13:37:50.599 -> >>Check module status ........OK
```

I tried subscribing and publishing using AT command using the hardware serial code and it's working fine, which indicates that there is some issue with the [code](https://github.com/AIS-DeviceInnovation/Magellan_SIM7020E/blob/master/examples/MQTT/SimplePUBSUB/SimplePUBSUB.ino) provided by the company.

AT Serial Commands to subscribe and publish.

```
AT+CMQNEW="broker.hivemq.com","1883",12000,100
AT+CMQCON=0,3,“myclient”,600,0,0
AT+CMQSUB=0, “my/test/topic”,1  
AT+CMQPUB=0,"my/test/topic",1,0,0,24,"48656c6c6f202d204d515454"
```

How can I fix the [code](https://github.com/AIS-DeviceInnovation/Magellan_SIM7020E/blob/master/examples/MQTT/SimplePUBSUB/SimplePUBSUB.ino) so it does not stuck in the reboot loop?

I have found the problem is similar to [this stackoveflow problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123580/how-to-fix-guru-meditation-error-core-1-paniced-loadprohibited-exception-w), but i don't know where to start to fix in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library has some issues with ESP32 core 2.0+. So downgrading ESP32 Core to 1.0.6 solved the issue.
Source: [Github](https://github.com/AIS-DeviceInnovation/Magellan_SIM7020E/issues/17?fbclid=IwAR3bRIcK5-gwGpk9-l-JTKaQ50k5YEVbTzhIiwcQh06czlIYJDiRm5G2ojg)